# Append (1),(2) after duplicated folder name in PHP

Tags: php, mkdir

Currently I have to create a folder similar in window file system.

For example: if folder is exist , add (1) at the end , if (1) is exist , add (2) at the end,
the problem is , are there standard function in PHP or I have to write my own function?

```
if (isdir($folderPath)) {

        $folderPath =  ...special handling or any PHP standard function ..
        mkdir($folderPath);

}
```

From reading PHP manual , so far there is no similar parameter for me to handle this? Are there any function besides mkdir will work ?Thanks

Comment: there is not many ways to create a folder. check the `spl` library it might have some classes which does the same as `mkdir`

Comment: You could possibly use [is_dir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php). Part of storing data is that you probably want to retrieve it too at some point. Is there nothing more unique you could use to logically structure your files? Edit: I see you are already using that (sleepy me!). Apart from that I don't think there is no fancy function that would make this easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any function that does this. A bruteforece approach comes to mind:

```
function make_filename($name) {
    if (file_exists($name)) {
        $i = 0;
        do {
            $testname = sprintf("%s (%d)", $name, ++$i);
        }
        while (file_exists($testname));
        return $testname;
    }
    return $name;
}

mkdir(make_filename("test"));
```

I wouldn't recommend this if you expect a LOT of duplicated filenames.